# AVSpeechUtterance 10% step rate changes

Tags: swift, xcode, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I need to implement `AVSpeechUtterance` rate change in range from 50% to 150% relative to normal speed with a step of 10%.

The problem is that I can't really find neither absolute, nor relative rate values to build on.
I do know that normal rate value is 0.5. But setting it to 0.6 at least doubles the speed.
Documentation mentions `AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate` and `AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate`, but I fail to understand how to make use of it since I can't even access it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean that you can't "access" AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate?  It's a constant provided by AVFoundation.  I was able to print it from a playground.

Comment: Could you show me how to to that?